# Vigenère Cipher Most of the test pass with the coding but some won't work any

Tags: javascript, algorithm, encryption

```
class VigenèreCipher {
    constructor(key, abc) {
        this.encode = function (str) {
            //split the string into an array
            let arr = abc.split("");
            let keyValue = [];

            for (let i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
                //finding the letter(key) value and push it to key value
                keyValue.push(arr.indexOf(key[i]));
            }
            let redacted = "";
            let pointer = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
                if (arr.includes(str[i])) {
                    let shift = arr.indexOf(str[i]) + keyValue[pointer];

                    if (shift >= 26) {
                        redacted += arr[shift - 26];
                    } else {
                        redacted += arr[shift];
                    }
                    //debugging code
                    console.log(
                        `string: ${str[i]}`,
                        `shift: ${shift - 26}`,
                        `shiftTo ${arr[shift]}`,
                        `pointer: ${pointer}`,
                        `KeyValue: ${keyValue[pointer]}`
                    );
                    pointer += 1;
                } else {
                    pointer = 0;
                    redacted += str[i];
                }

                if (pointer >= keyValue.length) {
                    pointer = 0;
                }
            }

            //console.log(keyValue);
            console.log(`redacted: ${redacted}`);
            return redacted
        };
        this.decode = function (str) {
            let arr = abc.split("");
            let keyValue = [];

            for (let i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
                //finding the letter(key) value and push it to key value
                keyValue.push(arr.indexOf(key[i]));
            }
            let decoded = "";
            let pointer = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
                if (arr.includes(str[i])) {
                    let shift = arr.indexOf(str[i]) - keyValue[pointer];
                    if (shift < 0) {
                        decoded += arr[26 - Math.abs((arr.indexOf(str[i]) - keyValue[pointer]))];
                    } else {
                        decoded += arr[Math.abs((arr.indexOf(str[i]) - keyValue[pointer]))];
                    }

                    //debugging code
                    console.log(
                        `string: ${str[i]} `,
                        `shift: ${arr.indexOf(str[i]) - keyValue[pointer]} `,
                        `shiftTo ${arr[arr.indexOf(str[i]) - keyValue[pointer]]} `,
                        `pointer: ${pointer} `,
                        `KeyValue: ${keyValue[pointer]} `,
                        `arrindex: ${arr.indexOf(str[i])} `,

                    );
                    pointer += 1;
                } else {
                    pointer = 0;
                    decoded += str[i];
                }

                if (pointer >= keyValue.length) {
                    pointer = 0;
                }
            }

            //console.log(keyValue);
            console.log(`decode: ${decoded}`);
            return decoded
        };
    };
}
```

**The Vigenère cipher is a method of encrypting alphabetic text by using a series of different 
Caesar ciphers based on the letters of a keyword. It is a simple form of polyalphabeticsubstitution.
In a Caesar cipher, each letter of the alphabet is shifted along some number of places; for example,in a Caesar cipher of shift 3, A would become D, B would become E, Y would become B and so on. The Vigenère cipher consists of several Caesar ciphers in sequence with different shift values. Assume the key is repeated for the length of the text, character by character. Note that some implementations repeat the key over characters only if they are part of the alphabet -- this is not the case here.The shift is derived by applying a Caesar shift to a character with the corresponding index of the key in the alphabet.**

```
**ar abc, key;
abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
key = "password"
c = new VigenèreCipher(key, abc);

Test.assertEquals(c.encode('codewars'), 'rovwsoiv');
Test.assertEquals(c.decode('rovwsoiv'), 'codewars');

Test.assertEquals(c.encode('waffles'), 'laxxhsj');
Test.assertEquals(c.decode('laxxhsj'), 'waffles');

Test.assertEquals(c.encode('CODEWARS'), 'CODEWARS');
Test.assertEquals(c.decode('CODEWARS'), 'CODEWARS');**

 **Expected: 'xt\'k o vwixl qzswej!', instead got: 'xt\'h p hhaxp rihzaf!'
Expected: 'it\'s a shift cipher!', instead got: 'it\'v z gwqfp bzaeiv!'**
**Expected: 'ドオカセガヨゴザキアニ', instead got: 'ドテタヒガォゴザキノイ'
Expected: 'ドモアリガトゴザイマス', instead got: 'ドタシェガホゴザイィス'**

**The code solve most problem but won't solve those any idea whats going on or how to fix it?**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information given in the post states

> ... **Note that some implementations repeat the key over characters only if they are part of the alphabet -- this is not the case here. ...**

To achieve this you increment the pointer and/or set it to zero after processing each and **every** character. You could put the unconditional update of `pointer` immediately before the end of loop, removing other pointer updates, like

```
    ...
    pointer += 1;
    if( pointer >= keyValue.length) {
        pointer = 0
    }
} // end of for loop
```

or by calculating it directly as

```
    pointer = (pointer + 1) % keyValue.length;
```

This gets the code to encode `"it's a shift cipher!"` as `"xt'k o vwixl qzswej!"` as expected, and decode that result back to the original without error (after fixing pointer updating in both `encode` and `decode` of course).

Answer (score 0):

You reset the pointer to zero in the `else` when you detect a character that is not in the alphabet. In general, you only increase the "pointer" within the key if you encrypt and *otherwise you leave it alone*, you don't reset it.

Comment: That didnt solve the problem the problem thanks anyways any other solution?

Comment: There are probably multiple bugs in that case, because this is certainly wrong. Tried a debugger? You've also hardcoded 26?